# Linear Algebra regarding the vector and scalar products

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let us fix vectors $r_0$ and $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $u\ne0$.

Using the identity $u×(v×w) = (u·w)v−(u·v)w$,
for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, show that if $r×u = r_0 ×u$, then there exists $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$ (which you should determine) such that
$r = r_0 +tu$.

Hint: take the vector product of both sides of the equation with $u$.

My progress so far..From the hint, I have taken the vector product of both sides with $u \times u$ = $0$ on the right hand side of the equation, leaving me with $0$ =  ($u·w)v× u−(u·v)w×u$. I am unsure of what the next step to take is. The next step may be made easier if I have the equation in the form $0 = u×((u.w)v-(u.v)w)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! When asking our questions, we like to use Mathjax formatting; take a look at this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and format your question.

Comment: This seems much like homework. You should add the progress you've made and tell where you're stuck.

Comment: It is a question from a past test. Hope the progress I have added helps. Apologies for the lack of clarity in the initial post, I am getting used to using the website. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Follow the hint.

Hint 2 (Alternative mathod): $(r-r_0)\times u=0$.

---

See also a Gowers's post about "[fake difficulty](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/welcome-to-the-cambridge-mathematical-tripos/)".